# Keep my Bootstrap Modal open after Form submission

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-modal

I have the Modal with Contact Form in my WordPress:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="contactUs" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="contactUs" aria-hidden="true">


<form id="contactOnline" method="POST">
 <input name="message_name" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="messageName" placeholder="Full name" required>
 <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-on" onclick="$('#contactUs').modal({'backdrop': 'static'}, 'show');">Submit</button>
 <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
</form>

</div>
```

I am trying to keep the Modal open even after the Form submission with `onclick="$('#contactUs').modal({'backdrop': 'static'}, 'show');`, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Since your page will refresh after submit, it will not work. Try submitting the form in AJAX.